# Servidor de autenticação OAuth 2 em ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, autenticação, asp.net-web-api, oauth2

A empresa que trabalho desenvolver aplicativos internos, porém por questões de políticas, teremos um subdomínio para tratar de autenticações como por exemplo: login.dominio.com.br onde terá um app responsável por administrar os dados do cliente em um banco separado dos outros apps.

Dessa forma estou estudando mais a fundo Oauth, para entender melhor como funciona. Fiz alguns teste locais e pelo que entendi no modo simples o trecho de código abaixo que se localiza na classe Startup.cs configura o servidor de autorização:

```
 OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/services/authentication/oauth2/token"),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/services/authentication/oauth2/token/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            Provider = new AuthorizationServerProvider(service)
        };

        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
```

A classe AuthorizationServerProvider.cs fica responsável por acessar o banco e fazer as validações.

A primeira pergunta é: Eu preciso usar necessáriamente o ASP.NET Identity para administrar o meu banco? ou posso utilizar a documentação de implementação do Oauth junto ao AuthorizationServerProvider.cs para armazenar de forma manual no banco?

A outra questão é se consigo achar um modelo ou um post completo de como fazer toda essa implementação de forma que atenda esses requisitos? Pois tudo que acho na internet é apenas a configuração para outros providers como Facebook ou Google.

A questão é apenas "Criar meu próprio provider de autenticação", consumir seria outra etapa.

Comment: Um artigo completo e bem passo a passo sobre o que está tentando fazer: [Web Api – Adicionando autenticação (OAuth)](http://www.leonardohofling.com/blog/web-api-adicionando-autenticacao-oauth/)

Answer (score -3):

Em relação à sua primeira pergunta, não é estritamente necessário utilizar o ASP.NET Identity para administrar o banco de dados ao implementar OAuth. O ASP.NET Identity é uma solução integrada para gerenciar identidade e autenticação em aplicativos ASP.NET, mas você pode implementar suas próprias lógicas de banco de dados ao usar OAuth. A classe AuthorizationServerProvider que você mencionou pode ser configurada para interagir diretamente com o seu banco de dados para realizar validações personalizadas, sem depender do ASP.NET Identity.

No entanto, é importante garantir que suas implementações sigam as boas práticas de segurança e tratamento de dados sensíveis, pois o ASP.NET Identity inclui funcionalidades específicas para lidar com esses aspectos de maneira robusta.

Quanto à sua segunda pergunta, criar seu próprio provedor de autenticação OAuth é uma abordagem válida, mas pode ser desafiador devido à complexidade e aos requisitos de segurança envolvidos. Infelizmente, é verdade que muitos recursos disponíveis na internet se concentram em integrações com provedores externos, como Facebook ou Google.

Para criar um provedor de autenticação personalizado, você precisará entender profundamente os detalhes do protocolo OAuth e implementar cada parte adequadamente. Recomendo que você consulte a documentação oficial do OAuth (https://www.oauth.net/) para uma compreensão completa do protocolo e, se possível, procure exemplos de implementações personalizadas para orientação prática.

Lembre-se sempre de seguir as melhores práticas de segurança ao implementar autenticação e autorização em seus aplicativos.

Espero que isso ajude no desenvolvimento do seu sistema de autenticação personalizado